# MS-Access, update a value based on what the client wants using forms

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, append, sql-delete

I have to create a form where you select your studentID and what class you want to change to. For example:

Student Table

```
StudentID Student Name      Class
1         John Smith        Biology
2         Elan Carter       Math
3         Bob White         Literature
```

In my form I ask for the student number and the associated information pulls up (I have this working correctly).

Form

```
What is your StudentID?  1

Student Name:   John Smith
Class:          Biology
```

Now I want another option to be able to change class. Let's say for example, change studentID 1's (John Smith) current class from Biology to Math

Updated

```
What class do you want to transfer to?   Math
Student Name:   John Smith
Class:          Biology
```

I considered the append and delete version but currently working on using the update query:

```
UPDATE Student
SET Student.[Student Name] = ""
WHERE
```

I'm confused because I don't understand how I can complete the query while taking into consideration of the multiple options. Thank you!

**PS-- I'm using queries to create the data in the form in MS ACCESS if there is any confusion.
**PSS---Tried this code but no success (Syntax error at JOIN operation)

```
UPDATE Student.[Student Name]
INNER JOIN Student ON Class.[Student Name] = Student.[Student Name]
SET Student.[Student Name] = Student.[Student Name]
```

If you're wondering about the Class table it's just:

```
Class
Biology
Math
Literature
```

Comment: Why not just select the class from a combobox bound to the Student table Class field? Students can't have more than one class?

Comment: No. Students are only allowed one class in this example.

Comment: This is a simple update query, possible from "Design View"... no joins, no sql, just populate the UpdateTo: with the fully qualified name, of the control containing the new value. This will probably get flagged as duplicate or off topic, as soon as someone with enough rep sees it...